# CSS transition for transform property without rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I need to transform an element with rotation, I want to animate (with transition) the transform but not the rotation.

```
<html>

 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <style>
     .transF{
         transform:translate3d(150px, 100px, 0px) rotateZ(-50deg);
         transition : transform 3s linear;
      }
   </style>
   <script>
      var add = function(){
        $("#test").addClass("transF"); 
      }
      var remove = function(){
        $("#test").removeClass("transF"); 
      }
   </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
    <div id="test">test</div>
 </body>

</html>
```

[Plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/NBBXNGgBYQDoOkxar93B?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can `transition` a *specific* property - use `animation` instead:

1. *animate* the `translate3d`
2. preserve the `rotateZ` value while the animation is happening

See demo below:

```js
var add = function() {
  $("#test").addClass("transF");
}
var remove = function() {
  $("#test").removeClass("transF");
}
```

```css
.transF {
  transform: translate3d(150px, 100px, 0px) rotateZ(-50deg);
  animation: translate 3s linear;
}
@keyframes translate {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateZ(-50deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(150px, 100px, 0px) rotateZ(-50deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Comment: your code work but I wonder if there is another solution because there is a third party that change the div translate3d and rotateZ so i can't do it statically

Answer (score 0):

You can change the  to this one.

```
<style>
  .transF
  {
  transform:translate3d(150px, 100px, 0px);
  transition : transform 3s linear;
  }
</style>
```

Just remove the rotateZ(-50deg).

Thank you.

Comment: I need to rotate it but without animation